# Calling close on passed in member StringWriter to XMLTextWriter

Tags: c#, serialization, xmltextwriter, stringwriter

I found some code that was not correctly wrapping XMLTextWriter and StringWriter with the using clauses.   As I'm correcting it, I stumbled on a interesting question:

do I have to explicitly add calls to Close() on each writer or does XMLTextWriter handle calling Close() on StringWriter instance automatically?

```
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }

        // is stringWriter.Close();  required here?
    }
```

Thnx
Matt

Comment: I have edited my answer. I hope it helps about your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is not required if the class in your `using` statement implements `IDisposable` correctly (in this case if `StringWriter` and `XmlTextWriter` call their `Close` methods in the `Dispose` method implementation).

At the end of a `using` block the `Dispose` method will automatically be called.

From the *Reference Source* of the [XmlTextWriter.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextWriter.cs,236b15253770e9c4) class you can see the following line in the `Close()` method

```
textWriter.Close();
```

where the `textWriter` was received in constructor, so the answer to your question is that you **don't need** to call the `Close()` method on your `StringWriter` instance, but doing so will do no harm.

For more info about `IDisposable` check out [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: is that maybe .NET version specific?

Comment: The source is for .NET 4.6, but i doubt that it changed from previous versions.

Comment: Im looking at 4.5.1 and I do not see it calling close on the input.  Maybe Im not looking in the right place.